# Question on a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Let it be of  degree $n$ and $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ be its roots. I know that 
$$
\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_i) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_j).
$$
What I was curious is 
does $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$?
If this is not the case, is there a known formula for
$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n) : \mathbb{Q}  ]$? Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$.  for a "general" polynomial, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n) : \mathbb{Q}  ]=n!$, i.e. a general polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has the full symmetric group as its galois group.

Comment: Usually that does not hold. For example if $p(x)=x^3-2$ and $\alpha_1$ is the only real zero, then $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$ cannot contain the other roots for they are complex. On the other hand with $p(x)=x^2-2$ you do get this. I think your wish is fulfilled, iff the Galois group is abelian.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the helpful comments!